# Есть ли Варианты используя JavaScript или другие методы определить реальный браузер пользователя?

Tags: javascript, браузер, идентификация

Существуют способы изменения User-Agent заголовка браузера, причём такие что влияют они и на изменение HTTP заголовков и при вызовах JavaScript. Интересует: существуют ли методы выполнения JavaScript такие что выполняться в разных браузерах они будут по разному и на основе отличий проводить идентификацию браузеров, в особенности современных и в особенности хрома, фаерфокса и оперы. Возможно у этих браузеров есть уникальные фишки, например методы JS которые возможно выполнить только в этой версии браузера.

Comment: гляньте в сторону css @supports и редких css свойств, например вендорных.

Comment: как затем проверить с помощью JavaScript что эти свойства выполнились и получить в результате в переменную что то вроде check = true/false; в зависимости от результата? Думаю над вариантами с длиной элементов и так далее, только опять же как их получить в переменную?

Comment: css: `@suppotrs (-moz-box-shadow){#x{background: orange;}} @suppotrs (-o-box-shadow){#x{background: red;}}` а дальше в js обычный switch(document.getElementById("x").style.background). вроде так.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browsers